# Install new version of npm and use it instead of the shared one

Tags: node.js, npm

We are many persons who work on the same server where our projects live. Every one of course has his own virtual environment.

We all share the same [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) `v4.4.5` and [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) `2.15.5`.

However, I need `npm >= 3.0.0`, so I installed a newer version `/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin/npm` and I added aliases for `node` and `npm` into my `~/.bashrc`

```
 # ~/.bashrc
alias node='/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin/node'
alias npm='/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin/npm'
```

Then I sourced it `source ~/.bashrc` and I thought it worked because

```
$ npm --version
5.0.3
```

Until I run [npm run dev](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack#usage)

```
$ npm run dev

> training@1.0.0 dev /home/users/itsme/projects/training
> /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin/node build/dev-server.js


To use this template, you must update following to modules:

npm: 2.15.5 should be >= 3.0.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! training@1.0.0 dev: `/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin/node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the training@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/users/itsme/.npm/_logs/2017-07-06T15_13_11_912Z-debug.log
```

I don't understand why it seems to be running the shared outdated `npm` instead of mine.

And here another quite weird thing

```
$ which npm # shows the shared one

$ `which npm` --version
2.15.5
```

Comment: What is the result of `which npm`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the shared one and not mine. Sorry I thought it was clear, updated my question

Comment: Then this is presumably an artifact of how you have your shell set up.  Have you sourced `~/.bashrc` (or started a new shell) since you updated it?  Is the old `npm` accessed via your `$PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're right!! adding `export PATH="/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin:$PATH"` has solved my problem (by overwritting old npm I guess), thx. Please add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved my problem (based on [Oliver Charlesworth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953192/install-new-version-of-npm-and-use-it-instead-of-the-shared-one#comment76882486_44953192))

```
export PATH="/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.1.3/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Node version manager makes managing multiple node environments a simple task.